# Does it make sense to work on a c# project, for a windows server, developing it on linux?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server

I'm a PHP/JS developer, now I have a proposition of making a project based on C#, which would then work on a Windows server.

I have no experience with either (C# or Windows server) but I was given some time to learn it, if we agree on the details.

The project is about an API (web service, RESTful).

And now I have two questions - I haven't touched Windows for about 10 years, so:

- Am I right that I have to learn C# **and** the .NET framework? Is the .NET some sort of standard on MS servers?
- Is this reasonable to work on the project using Linux machine as the work environment and then upload it to the Windows test server for testing?

BTW, right now the project is very simple, probably only a few classes. If I'll make it, I can later install Windows on my workspace, but for this very small project, where time allowed for the implementation is about one day (excluding my learning process) I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Since you say you have no experience, there's some important question to ask. Are you creating a new application Can you use .NET Core or .NET 5? Do you have to deploy on Windows (.NET Core or .NET 5 can be deployed on Linux)?

Comment: You should develop this on dotnet core (or as @omajid said on .net 5), should you decide to build your API using .net technology stack. However, PHP and nodejs are also fully supported on Windows so pick whatever what you are most comfortable with.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Question does not sound like OP has a choice in tech stack, much.

Comment: @omajid - I asked this question to the client and waiting for an answer, in the mean time I have read that 5.x is mostly backward compatible (with a few changes in the code), so I guess I'll take some code from them and see what will come up with 5.x. 

I would love to use PHP / Nodejs, but I don't have a choice. I have to stick to the .NET and I hope 5.x will be backward compatible enough :) If it's not, it seems I'll have to install Windows :(

Comment: @Fildor - yeah, unfortunatelly I don't really have. Now I'm only wondering how long will it take to learn all these new things, considering I'm a senior php/js dev (8 years of experience and some really big projects). But my guess it is impossible to predict it :)

BTW, thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. C# is a programming language, .NET is a framework. There is an old .NET Framework that is windows only and the newer .NET Core (the newest version is called just .NET 5), which is cross-platform.
2. You can develop .NET core apps on linux as well. Note that you won't be able to use Visual Studio (IDE), which is only available for Windows and Mac.

Comment: On Point 2: It's not very comfi, but you could use VS Code in Linux, or Rider (if this is just an "assessment project" with the 30day trial - no community ed, there) for an IDE.

Comment: Thanks! I use VS Code, and apparently it works fine, so Visual Studio not working is not an issue for me :)

Comment: @Fildor - yeah, I hoped so, because VS Code is what I use on a daily basis. I hope it will be working just fine :)